# I can't push multiple files to Github from Coda 2

Tags: github, git-commit, coda

I cloned my Github repository into local machine.

I'm using Coda to create new files. If I create some files and I try to push all them to my remote repository from **`File > Source Control > Commit All Changes`** Coda says commiting, but the files not are arriving to Github.

I can only commit the files one by one, using the optios of `SCM` at Coda's right panel:

[image]

There is one possibility of push multiple files into one commit? How I can achieve this?

Mi versión of Coda is `2.7.5`